# Enable users to manage IAP subscriptions on iOS

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscriptions

Is there a good way to help users manage their IAP subscriptions?

According to Apple's [In-App Purchase Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH7-DontLinkElementID_1), the way to do this is to redirect to this URL: https://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/manageSubscriptions

But when I do that (using `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:...]`, Safari opens and then redirects to iTunes. Not only is iTunes flaky about responding, but it leaves the user in a confusing place, inside iTunes with a "Back to Safari" link at the top left. There is no breadtrail back to the app they came from - a crummy experience.

Comment: would this be a auto-renewable subscription each month

Comment: Yes, that's what I had in mind, although it doesn't have to be monthly.

Comment: right ok, and is this in Swift or Obj-C?

Comment: the only thing i could think of to make this work would be to use a UIWebViewController. You could always use the 3rd party one fro GitHub. Because surely by doing so, it would redirect them from your app rather then having to load safari and then they can go back to your app at the top.

GitHub 3rd Party: https://github.com/TransitApp/SVWebViewController

Comment: @Konsy Good suggestion. I will try loading the URL into a WKWebView and then when it redirects to iTunes, I expect it to point back to my app. Was just lazy using openURL. :)

Comment: let me know if it works :)